# strange behavior with exception (some method not called is executed)

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I've been struggling with a really strange behavior that I do not manage to resolve on my own, so here I am.

I'm creating an GUI for a console application which works great. The user can either select a file to be loaded or reload a previous selected file. Those two actions are handled with two different `slots`. I'm handling errors in the file's format with `exceptions` and it worked great in the console version, but for the GUI not too well for the moment...

When an error is thrown in the openFile `slot`, the `catch` block makes his work and the method is stopped as expected BUT then the other slot is being called unexpectedly. I have no idea why and so have no idea how to correct that behavior.

Here's the relevant code :

```
void Loader::openSourceFile()
{
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(myWindow, tr("Select source file"), QString(), tr("Text files (*.txt)"));
    try{
        parseSourceFile();
    } catch(MyException &e)
    {
        QString msg = QString(e.what());
        myWindow->alertUser(msg);
        return;
    }
}

void Loader::reloadSourceFile()
{
    try{
        parseSourceFile();
    } catch(MyException &e)
    {
        QString msg = QString(e.what());
        myWindow->alertUser(msg);
        return;
    }
}
```

the context of use :

```
myLoader = new Loader(this);
menuTop = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));

//open source file
openAction = new QAction(QIcon(":images/document.png"), tr("&Open"), this);
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), myLoader, SLOT(openSourceFile()));
menuTop->addAction(openAction);

//reload source file
reloadAction = new QAction(QIcon(":images/reload.png"), tr("&Reload"), this);
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), myLoader, SLOT(reloadSourceFile()));
menuTop->addAction(reloadAction);
```

Note : after heavy debugging, I found that one function in the moc file of that class is being called after the execution of the catch block :

```
void Loader::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        Q_ASSERT(staticMetaObject.cast(_o));
        Loader *_t = static_cast<Loader *>(_o);
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->openSourceFile(); break;
        case 1: _t->reloadSourceFile(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}
```

it is called with _id = 1 which explain the undesired execution of the other slot. But why this happens ??? Does anybody could explain how this can be avoided ? I've already made my own application class derived from `qApplication` and override `notify()` but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should:

```
reloadAction = new QAction(QIcon(":images/reload.png"), tr("&Reload"), this);
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), myLoader, SLOT(reloadSourceFile()));
menuTop->addAction(reloadAction);
```

be:

```
reloadAction = new QAction(QIcon(":images/reload.png"), tr("&Reload"), this);
connect(reloadAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), myLoader, SLOT(reloadSourceFile()));
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
menuTop->addAction(reloadAction);
```

Comment: Ah I love you ! Thanks for pointing my stupid copy/paste error which made me lost several hours...

Comment: @Ote - happens to us all.  I usually ask a coworker to just read the code when I have something stupid happening.